# Zend Form - Not displaying

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to create a new Zend_Form. I tried to follow the documentation but nothing is displayed on my screen. 
Here's my code :

form/numero.php :

```
<?php

class Front_Form_Numero extends Zend_Form
{
  public function __construct()
    {
        // Constructeur du parent
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAttrib('action', '/index/numform/');

        /* ###################################  tel                  ################################### */
        $tel            = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('tel');
        $tel            ->setLabel("N° tél");
        $tel            ->setAttrib('class','text');
        $tel            ->setRequired(true);
        $tel            ->addFilter('StringTrim')->addDecorators(array('clearfix'=>new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'clearfix'))));
        $tel            ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(0, 10));
        $tel            ->setAttrib('maxlength', '10');

         /* ###################################  submit               ################################### */
        $submit         = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit         ->setLabel("")->addDecorators(array('clearfix'=>new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'clearfix'))));
        $submit         ->setAttrib('class','submit btn btn-primary ico-btn-valider');
        $this           ->addElement($submit);

    }
}
```

controllers/indexController.php :

```
 public function numformAction() {
    // Création du formulaire
    $this->view->numform = new Front_Form_Numero();


    // Si le formulaire a été posté
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        // Si le formulaire est valide
        if($numform->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()))
        {
            // Données postées
            $numero = $numform->getValues();
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

                if ($validTel->isValid($numero)) 
                {
                   echo "OK";
                } else {
                    echo "NO OK ";    
                }
            }



        }
    }

    echo $numform;
    exit;
```

}
view helper :

```
 $bdd_NumTel = new Front_Model_DbTable_NumTel();
    $this->view->numeros = $bdd_NumTel->fetchAll($bdd_NumTel->select()
                                                            ->from('num_tel',
                                                              array('name','numero'))                                                                                   
                                                );        

return $this;
```

view :

```
  <?php 
      echo $this->numform;
  ?>
```

I have to error message (or i don't know how to find them :D)
I have others forms and when i call $form it works
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Rather then overriding the constructor of Zend_Form you should create your form inside the init() method. If you don't have any good reasons for doing so.

As for your question you have made a mistake. The line

```
$numform = $this->view->form = new Front_Form_Numero();
```

should be

```
$this->view->numform = new Front_Form_Numero();
```